# JavaFX AceEditor

Tags: java, javascript, javafx

i have a problem with initializing the Ace editor inside WebView. The content of the HTML is shown (Sample Text), but if i'm trying to call a javascript function inside the HTML nothing happens. The javascript files are in the same folder as the HTML

The content of the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="editor.css">
</head>
<body>
    Sample text
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    var editor = document.createElement( 'div' );
    editor.id = "editor";
    editor.style.position = 'absolute';
    editor.style.left = '0px';
    editor.style.top = '0px';
    editor.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
    editor.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
    document.body.appendChild( editor );

    var ace = ace.edit("editor");
    ace.setTheme("ace/theme/chrome");
    ace.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/xml");
</script>
</html>
```

Initialization of WebView

```
WebEngine webEngine = ((WebView)scene.lookup("#myWebView")).getEngine();
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("../../../html/editor.html").toExternalForm());
```

Thanks

Comment: Which js code are you trying to run? Does it work in normal Chrome browser?

Comment: Inside a browser i.e. Firefox it works pretty well also inside the eclipse browser. I just tried to add an element <p>

Comment: Edit your question and add the code in html which you tried to run.